# Postgres Update add to array and if larger than 5 remove last

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I have a little program that collects local news headlines all over a country. It should collect the top headline every day in an array and if it has more than 5 headlines, it should remove the oldest one and add the newest one at the top.

Heres the table:

```
CREATE TABLE place{
     name text PRIMARY KEY,
     coords text,
     headlines json[]
}
```

The headlines array is basically just json objects with a time and headline property, that would be upserted like this:

```
insert into place VALUES ('giglio','52.531677;13.381777',
                      ARRAY[
'{"timestamp":"2012-01-13T13:37:27+00:00","headline":"costa concordia sunk"}'
]::json[]) 
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT place_pkey DO
UPDATE SET headlines = place.headlines || EXCLUDED.headlines
```

But obviously as soon at it hits 5 elements in the array, it will keep adding onto it.  So is there a way to add these headlines and limit them to 5?

Alternative Solution:

```
insert into place VALUES ('giglio','52.531677;13.381777',
                      ARRAY[
'{"timestamp":"2012-01-13T13:37:27+00:00","headline":"costa concordia sunk"}'
]::json[]) 
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT place_pkey DO
UPDATE SET headlines = place.headlines[0:4] || EXCLUDED.headlines
RETURNING *
```

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but in my opinion `jsonb[]` hardly ever makes sense. Using `jsonb` with a "native" JSON array inside is usually the better choice.

Comment: well its json, not jsonb. But doesn't that making merging, operating on, indexing and querying arrays harder?

Comment: If you need to search inside arrays, chances are that you want a properly normalized data model to begin with.

Comment: `json` with an array means `json` field, but `json[]` means array of jsons - not really the same thing. And for OP question, `json[]` seems to be a better choice.

Comment: so whats the advantage with your approach then? Because at least merging 2 arrays is obviously necessary

Comment: I recommend not to abuse JSON and arrays here. The schema seems pretty static and thus should simply be modeled by relational means, tables and columns. And then you should simply add the data and limit the result to five or whatever number when querying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I ended up doing it:

```
insert into place VALUES ('giglio','52.531677;13.381777',
                      ARRAY[
'{"timestamp":"2012-01-13T13:37:27+00:00","headline":"costa concordia sunk"}'
]::json[]) 
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT place_pkey DO
UPDATE SET headlines = place.headlines[0:4] || EXCLUDED.headlines
RETURNING *
```

EXCLUDED explanation

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/sql-insert.html

Comment: Can you explain where this `EXCLUDED` comes from?

Comment: The excluded row is the row you wanted to insert. meaning you add to the existing place.headlines the headlines you just inserted

Answer (score 1):

> So is there a way to add these headlines and limit them to 5?

I believe yes.

You can define max array size

(search section 8.15.1 here https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html#ARRAYS-DECLARATION)

like this

```
headlines json[5]
```

But current implementation of Postgres does not enforce it (still good to do it for future compatibility and proper data model definition).

So I'd try if `CHECK` constraint is of any help here:

```
headlines json[5] CHECK (array_length(headlines) < 6)
```

This should give you a basic consistency check. From here there are two ways to continue (which seems out of the scope of this question):

1. Catch the PG exception on your app layer, clean up the data, and try inserting it again
2. Implement [a function in your DB schema](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/sql-createfunction.html), that would attempt insert and cleanup.

Comment: thanks. I since found a third method and added it to my post

Comment: Nice, I'd suggest adding it as an answer as well.